# Android Custom Font rendering issue

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to change my listview font.I created `assets/fonts` folder. I added  `OpenSans-Regular.ttf` in this folder. I added `typeface` line in my Adapter class.
Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<String> listFunds;
    Typeface typeface;


    Context mContext;

    public Adapter(Context mContext, List<String> listFunds) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.listFunds = listFunds;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listFunds.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(listFunds.get(position));
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/"+"OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);


        return row;
    }
}
```

However, the font doesn't seem as it should be. I tried many fonts, but nothing changed.

My app seems like this:

[image: screenshot of my app]

But, font should seem like this
[image: openSans-Regular]

Comment: Are you running the app on a physical device or on an emulator?

Comment: on an Android emulator. @Jonas

Comment: Be aware that emulators are known to have troubles rendering graphics correctly. I would strongly recommend you to run the app on a physical device.

Comment: Thanks! the problem arises from the emulator. I am using GenyMotion, font looks good now :) @Jonas

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put this `typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/"+"OpenSans-Regular.ttf");` in the constructor for effeciency. It could also be the one causing you problems. Or maybe change the font file that you are using, to me it also looks like it might be of a diffent language from English characters.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!I tried this also. As @Jonas said, an emulator is a problem.